# Iseries SQL update

Tags: sql, db2-400

Table 1

```
Column1  Column2
aa         12
bb         12
cc         12
aa         12
bb         12
```

Table 2

```
Column1  Column2
aa         12
bb         13
cc         14
aa         15
bb         16
```

Now, using Sql query I need to update table1.column2 with table2.column2  based on table2 to column1 and table1.column1 records

```
update Table1 a set a.Column2 = ( select b.Column2from Table2
b where A.column1= b.column1)
```

The above query raises the error:

> Null values not allowed in column or variable.

I'm trying to copy data between 2 different systems.

Comment: Show us the expected result too. (But why do you store such similar data in two tables. And why copy data?)

Comment: After executing above query result "Null values not allowed in column or variable"..i'm trying to copy data from 2 different systems.

Comment: The example data that was given [for which the DDL was omitted, but is quite relevant], would not have produced the error claimed to have been seen; instead of that error -407 aka SQL0407 "Null values not allowed in column or variable COLUMN2.", the effect would have been sqlcode=-811 aka SQL0811 "Result of SELECT more than one row."  Correct the OP to provide correction to the example data [might just as well add the DDL] to exhibit the error claimed to be seen.  Or perhaps instead\also change to clarify what exactly is the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like there are table1 rows without any matching table2 row. In that case the sub-query returns NULL. And I guess table1.column2 doesn't allow NULL's?

Add a `WHERE` clause to only update rows with matches in table2.

```
update Table1 a set a.Column2 = (select b.Column2 from Table2 b
                                 where A.column1= b.column1)
where exists (select 1 from Table2 b2
              where A.column1= b2.column1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @jarih's answer..

If your on a currently supported release, ie. 7.1 or higher...

You could use `MERGE`

```
merge into table1 A
using (select column1, column2 from table2) as B
on a.column1 = b.column1
when matched then
 update set a.column2 = b.column2
```